# Action on Select in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following issue:

1) I have `DropDown1` with some names of cars.

2) I have `DropDown2` with two values:

In DropDown2, the following should happen on select of each values:

a) On selecting UserInput, the left hand side multiselect box should get hidden and **in the same place**, a textbox should appear. User can write any car name in the text box and then use the left to right button to move that value to right hand side select box. Right to left button should be disable in this case.

b) On selecting AutoPopulate, a multiselect box should appear on left hand side in the same place as the textbox and the textbox should get hidden. The multiselect box should get populated with car list from DropDown1. User should be able to select and move cars from left to right and right to left.

I am new to Javascript. Could someone please help me with this.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40awnzhw/6/)

```js
$(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");
        });
    });
    
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#list2 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");
        });
    });
});
```

```css
 .bloc { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; overflow:hidden; border:solid grey 1px; width:100px;}
 .bloc select { padding:10px; margin:-5px -20px -5px -5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
DropDown1:
<select id="DropDown1" name="DropDown1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><br>
DropDown2:
<select id="DropDown2" name="DropDown2">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="oneUsrInput">User Input</option>
  <option value="twoAutoPopulate">Auto Populate</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="TextBoxId" name="TextBoxId">
<div class="bloc">     
    <select id="list1" multiple="multiple" rows=2>
        <option value=1>Option 1</option>
        <option value=2>Option 2</option>
        <option value=3>Option 3</option>
        <option value=4>Option 4</option>
        <option value=5>Option 5</option>
        <option value=6>Option 6</option>
    </select>
   </div>
 <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <input id="button1" type="button" value=">>" />
    <br/>
    <input id="button2" type="button" value="<<" />
 </div>
<div class="bloc">
    <select id="list2" multiple="multiple" rows=2>        
    </select>   
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Your fiddle was created wrongly. You needed to click the [JAVASCRIPT] button and use "In Head" instead of adding external script and use onload. Here is the [fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57tu5uz2/). I also added your code to a snippet in your question

Comment: @mplungjan: thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet that does that. It also verifies that you cannot add the same text twice to the list:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        if ($('#DropDown2').val() === 'oneUsrInput') {
            var txt = $('#TextBoxId').val();
            $('#TextBoxId').val('');
            // add text only when not already existing in list:
            if (!$('#list2').val(txt).val()) {
                $('<option/>').text(txt).val(txt).appendTo('#list2');
            }
        } else {
            $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
                $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");
            });
        }
    });
    
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#list2 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");
        });
    });
    
    $("#DropDown2").change(function() {
        var isUserInput = $(this).val() === 'oneUsrInput';
        $('#TextBoxId').toggle(isUserInput);
        $('#list1,#button2').toggle(!isUserInput);
    });
    
    // at start up, populate multi-select list    
    $("#list1").html($("#DropDown1").html()); 
    // at start up, set visibility right:
    $("#DropDown2").change();
});
```

```css
.bloc { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; overflow:hidden; 
        border:solid grey 1px; width:100px;}
.bloc select { padding:10px; margin:-5px -20px -5px -5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
DropDown1:
<select id="DropDown1" name="DropDown1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><br>DropDown2:
<select id="DropDown2" name="DropDown2">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="oneUsrInput">User Input</option>
    <option value="twoAutoPopulate">Auto Populate</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<div class="bloc">     
    <input type="text" id="TextBoxId" style="display:none" name="TextBoxId">
    <select id="list1" multiple="multiple" rows=2>
    </select>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <input id="button1" type="button" value=">>" />
    <br/>
    <input id="button2" type="button" value="<<" />
</div>
<div class="bloc">
    <select id="list2" multiple="multiple" rows=2></select>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. any pointers on how to populate multiselect with values from DropDown1 ?

Comment: Does this mean you will have the same values in dropdown1 and the multiselect? If so, and if the multiselect is re-populated, do you want the right-side to be cleared? Or if not, is it not a problem to  have the same values in the right list (previously selected) and also in the left one?

Comment: Anyway, I have updated the snippet: it now loads the car names in the multi select list. As it is kept in place, even when hidden, it is not repopulated again. I don't think this is necessary. Can you confirm? Also what is the use of selecting a car in the first drop down list?

Comment: Thanks... you are right.. Multiselect should be dependent on DropDown1. So on page load, based on the option values coming in DropDown1, the multiselect should get populated. User can select 1 value from DropDown1 and multiple from DropDown2 and TextBoxes. Finally everything will be part of a Post Submit.

Comment: Wait: do you want the list of values to be different depending on the selection in dropdown1? If so, can you provide the values for each possible selection? I assume they are different per selected car? For instance what do you want have as options for Volvo, and what do want if they select Saab? Another list? Should the change of car selection have any effect?

Comment: No. The page is a result of two three different flows. And for each flow, the option values in DropDown1 would be different. And in each case, the multiselect should get populated with whatever options are present in DropDown1. The only dependency between DropDown1 and Multiselect is, MultiSelect should not have the value already selected in DropDown1. But this is trivial and I will be able to do it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

More precised code:

```
$(function() {
  var value = 100;
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    if ($("#DropDown2").val() == "oneUsrInput") {
      console.log();
      $("<option value=" + (value++) + ">" + $("#TextBoxId").val() + "</option>").appendTo("#list2");
    } else if ($("#DropDown2").val() == "twoAutoPopulate") {
      $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function() {
        $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");
      });
    }
  });

  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#list2 > option:selected").each(function() {
      $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");
    });
  });
  $("#DropDown2").on('change', function() {
    if ($("#DropDown2").val() == "oneUsrInput") {
      $("#TextBoxId").show();
      $("#list1").parent().hide();
    } else if ($("#DropDown2").val() == "twoAutoPopulate") {
      $("#TextBoxId").hide();
      $("#list1").parent().show();
    }
  })
});
```

Do you need more help? or you can go ahead?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/40awnzhw/8/)

Comment: Why not copy code to answer and have it all live here?

Comment: @mplungjan: Didn't get you

Comment: You create a fiddle instead of clicking "copy snippet code to answer" and modify. That keeps the answer and a working example here at SO

Comment: @ParagBhayani: Yes.. I need more help. How do I attach my textbox to the button action? I was able to make that work for the multiselect. And how do I update my multiselect with values from DropDown1? As you can see it has static values right now.

Comment: @ParagBhayani: Thanks.. I will figure out how to populate the multiselect with values of DropDown1,,,

Comment: @Vicky: So does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I did some edits to your code :

```
$(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
            if($('.userArea').hasClass('twoAutoPopulate')){
            $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
                $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");
                console.log($(this));
            });
        }
        else if($('.userArea').hasClass('oneUsrInput')){
            $('#list2').append($('<option>', { 
                value: $('#TextBoxId').val(),
                text : $('#TextBoxId').val() 
            }));
            $('#TextBoxId').val('')
        }
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
            if($('.userArea').hasClass('twoAutoPopulate')){
            $("#list2 > option:selected").each(function(){
                $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");
            });
        }
    });
});

$("#DropDown2").on('change', function() {
    $('.userArea').fadeIn(300);
    if($("#DropDown2").val() == "oneUsrInput") {
    $('.userArea').addClass('oneUsrInput').removeClass('twoAutoPopulate');
  }
  else if($("#DropDown2").val() == "twoAutoPopulate") {
    $('.userArea').addClass('twoAutoPopulate').removeClass('oneUsrInput');
  }
});
```

but I also made some edits to your css and HTML so see your demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/e6v3zvzn/